# dynamically set LinearLayout height/width in relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

i have a linearLayout inside a RelativeLayout. I need to be able to set the height of the linearlayout dynamically depending on the screen dimensions. Im having some difficulties. 
how can i achieve this?

MAIN :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout L;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    L=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.top);

    L.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(1080, 400));
}

}
```

XML:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"

 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What's the difficulty/problem?

Comment: @JustinJasmann i get this error -java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.findRoots(RelativeLayout.java:1722)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set layout params, it needs to be that of the parent.

Switch:

```
L.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(1080, 400));
```

To:

```
L.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(1080, 400));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you can do the following:

```
L.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(1080, 400)
```

And then call `L.requestLayout()` to apply changes

Answer (score 0):

in your LinearLayout, just set

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: I think you have to remove  L=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.top);

    L.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(1080, 400));

Answer (score 0):

As Justin answered

```
L.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(1080, 400));
```

You might also need, if you have already set the layout

```
L.requestLayout();
```